# How to reduce the time in this program?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, time, primes

I have a program like this: given a sequence of integers, find the biggest prime and its positon.

Example:

```
input:

9 // how many numbers
19 7 81 33 17 4 19 21 13

output:
19 // the biggest prime
1 7 // and its positon
```

So first I get the input, store it in an array, make a copy of that array and sort it (because I use a varible to keep track of the higest prime, and insane thing will happen if that was unsorted) work with every number of that array to check if it is prime, loop through it again to have the positon and print the result.

But the time is too slow, can I improve it?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
```

```
int main() 
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int numbersNotSorted[n];
    int maxNum{0};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> numbersNotSorted[i];
    }
    int numbersSorted[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        numbersSorted[i] = numbersNotSorted[i];
    }
    sort(numbersSorted, numbersSorted + n);
    for (int number = 0; number < n; number++)
    {
        int countNum{0};
        for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(numbersSorted[number]); i++)
        {
            if (numbersSorted[number] % i == 0)
                countNum++;
        }
        if (countNum == 0)
        {
            maxNum = numbersSorted[number];
        }
    }
    cout << maxNum << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (numbersNotSorted[i] == maxNum)
            cout << i + 1 << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. what's a faster operation? Checking if a number is prime, or checking if a number is greater than the current largest prime? 2. Instead identifying the largest prime, and then going back to find its position, just store its position once you find it.

Comment: Which part of this code is taking the most time? And have you tried running this code with pencil and paper, to see if you find yourself doing anything that seems pointless?

Comment: @JohnFilleau 1. Because the array is sorted, every number in the array is al least equal to the number before. 2. Because I sorted the array, I can't keep track of the number. Is there anything I don't understand because I'm a noob.

Comment: Sorting makes this less efficient then. If the array is sorted from lowest to highest, then you have to check if each number is prime. If you don't sort the array, you can skip checking primality if the one you're checking is less than the one that's the current maximum. If you're going to sort at all, iterate from largest to smallest value, and the first prime you find is the largest. You want to short circuit as much as possible

Comment: @Beta Yes I have tried running the code with pencil and paper, feel some of the part are pointless but needed in my approach

Comment: *"Pointless but needed in my approach"?* If you are unwilling to change your approach, then what do you think we can do for you?

Comment: @JohnFilleau Thank you!!. Very clever!!. I'm a noob.

Comment: @Beta I'm not unwilling to change my approach, I just think it's a good approach and I can't find a better one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes may also help. You have an assortment of tools, and it's up to you to find the complexity of each tool (iterating, sorting, sieving, etc.) and determine the total average complexity, best case complexity, and worst case complexity of the different combinations.

Comment: In addition to what @JohnFilleau said and if you are not using Sieve of Eratosthenes (It is useful when you have more than one sequence to check but in this case I can't recommend), then try to avoid running the second loop for all numbers by checking if that number is divisible by two or three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a basic "for each number entered" loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    int newNumber;

    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> newNumber;
    }
}
```

If the new number is smaller than the current largest prime, then it can be ignored.

```
int main() {
    int n;
    int newNumber;
    int highestPrime;
     
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> newNumber;
        if(newNumber >= highestPrime) {
        
        }
    }
}
```

If the new number is equal to the highest prime, then you just need to store its position somewhere. I'm lazy, so:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    int newNumber;
    int highestPrime;
    int maxPositions = 1234;
    int positionList[maxPositions];
    int nextPosition;
    int currentPosition = 0;
     
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> newNumber;
        currentPosition++;
        if(newNumber >= highestPrime) {
            if(newNumber == highestPrime) {
                if(nextPosition+1 >= maxPositions) {
                    // List of positions is too small (should've used malloc/realloc instead of being lazy)!
                } else {
                    positionList[nextPosition++] = currentPosition;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the new number is larger than the current largest prime, then you need to figure out if it is a prime number, and if it is you need to reset the list and store its position, etc:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    int newNumber;
    int highestPrime = 0;
    int maxPositions = 1234;
    int positionList[maxPositions];
    int nextPosition;
    int currentPosition = 0;
     
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> newNumber;
        currentPosition++;
        if(newNumber >= highestPrime) {
            if(newNumber == highestPrime) {
                if(nextPosition+1 >= maxPositions) {
                    // List of positions is too small (should've used malloc/realloc instead of being lazy)!
                } else {
                    positionList[nextPosition++] = currentPosition;
                }
            } else {   // newNumber > highestPrime
                if(isPrime(newNumber)) {
                    nextPosition = 0;           // Reset the list
                    highestPrime = newNumber;
                    positionList[nextPosition++] = currentPosition;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll also want something to display the results:

```
   if(highestPrime > 0) {
       for(nextPosition= 0; nextPosition < currentPosition; nextPosition++) {
           cout << positionList[nextPosition];
       }
   }
```

Now; the only thing you're missing is an `isPrime(int n)` function. The fastest way to do that is to pre-calculate a "is/isn't prime" bitfield. It might look something like:

```
bool isPrime(int n) {
    if(n & 1 != 0) {
        n >>= 1;
        if( primeNumberBitfield[n / 32] & (1 << (n % 32)) != 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem here is that (for positive values in a 32-bit signed integer) you'll need 1 billion bits (or 128 MiB).

To avoid that you can use a much smaller bitfield for numbers up to `sqrt(1 << 31)` (which is only about 4 KiB); then if the number is too large for the bitfield you can use the bitfield to find prime numbers and check (with modulo) if they divide the original number evenly.

Note that Sieve of Eratosthenes ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes ) is an efficient way to generate that smaller bitfield (but is not efficient to use for a sparse population of larger numbers).

If you do it right, you'll probably create the illusion that it's instantaneous because almost all of the work will be done while a human is slowly typing the numbers in (and not left until after all of the numbers have been entered). For a very fast typist you'll have ~2 milliseconds between numbers, and (after the last number is entered) humans can't notice delays smaller than about 10 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the biggest prime, sorting the array brings you no benefit, you'll need to check all the values stored in the array anyway.

Even if you implemented a fast sorting algorithm, [the best averages you can hope for are `O(N + k)`](https://lamfo-unb.github.io/2019/04/21/Sorting-algorithms/), so just sorting the array is actually more costly than looking for the largest prime in an unsorted array.

The process is pretty straight forward, check if the next value is larger than the current largest prime, and if so check if it's also prime, store the positions and/or value if it is, if not, check the next value, repeat until the end of the array.

`θ(N)` time compexity will be the best optimization possible given the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

> But the time is too slow, can I improve it?

Below loop suffers from:

1. Why check smallest values first?  Makes more sense to check largest values first to find the largest prime.  Exit the `for (... number..)` loop early once a prime is found.  This takes advantage of the work done by `sort()`.
2. Once a candidate value is not a prime, quit testing for prime-ness.

.

```
// (1) Start for other end rather than as below
for (int number = 0; number < n; number++) {
        int countNum {0};
        for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(numbersSorted[number]); i++) {
            if (numbersSorted[number] % i == 0)
                // (2) No point in continuing prime testing, Value is composite.
                countNum++;
        }
        if (countNum == 0) {
            maxNum = numbersSorted[number];
        }
    }
```

Corrections left for OP to implement.

3. Advanced: Prime testing is a deep subject and many optimizations (trivial and complex) exist that are better than OP's approach.  Yet I suspect the above 2 improvement will suffice for OP.

---

Brittleness: Code does not well handle the case of no primes in the list or `n <= 0`.

`i <= sqrt(numbersSorted[number])` is prone to FP issues leading to an incorrect results.  Recommend `i <= numbersSorted[number]/i)`.

Sorting is `O(n * log n)`.  Prime testing, as done here, is `O(n * sqrt(n[i]))`.  Sorting does not increase `O()` of the overall code when the square root of the max value is less than log of `n`.  Sorting is worth doing if the result of the sort is used well.

Code fails if the largest value was 1 as prime test incorrectly identifies 1 as a prime.

Code fails if `numbersSorted[number] < 0` due to `sqrt()`.

Simply full-range `int` prime test:

```
bool isprime(int num) {
  if (num % 2 == 0) return num == 2;
  for (int divisor = 3; divisor <= num / divisor; divisor += 2) {
    if (num % divisor == 0) return false;
  }
  return num > 1;
}
```

Comment: std::sqrt is required by the IEEE standard to be exact. You are adding one unneccessary division on every loop.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek 1) `std::sqrt` is not required to follow IEEE 754 as C++ does not require adherence to that IEEE standard. 2) Conversion of large `int` values to `float` as part of the `sqrt()` can lose precision resulting in incorrect results - even with IEEE adherence.  3) Good compilers see nearby `num / divisor` and `num % divisor` and emit optimized code by forming both results in one div/rem operation.  If concern remains, use `div()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the prime, don't go for sorting. You'll have to check for all the numbers present in the array then.

You can try this approach to do the same thing, but all within a lesser amount of time:

**Step-1:** Create a **global** function for detecting a prime number. Here's how you can approach this-

```
bool prime(int n)
{
    int i, p=1;
    for(i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++)  //note that I've iterated till the square root of n, to cut down on the computational time
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            p=0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(p==0)
    return false;
    else
    return true;
}
```

**Step-2:** Now your main function starts. You take input from the user:

```
int main()
{
    int n, i, MAX;
    cout<<"Enter the number of elements: ";
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    cout<<"Enter the array elements: ";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>arr[i];
```

**Step-3:** Note that I've declared a counter variable `MAX`. I initialize this variable as the first element of the array: `MAX=arr[0];`

**Step-4:** Now the loop for iterating the array. What I did was, I iterated through the array and at each element, I checked if the value is greater than or equal to the previous `MAX`. This will ensure, that the program does not check the values which are less than `MAX`, thus eliminating a part of the array and cutting down the time. I then nested another if statement, to check if the value is a prime or not. If both of these are satisfied, I set the value of `MAX` to the current value of the array:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>=MAX)   //this will check if the number is greater than the previous MAX number or not
        {
            if(prime(arr[i]))   //if the previous condition satisfies, then only this block of code will run and check if it's a prime or not
            MAX=arr[i];
        }
    }
```

What happens is this- The value of `MAX` changes to the max prime number of the array **after every single loop**.

**Step-5:** Then, after finally traversing the array, when the program finally comes out of the loop, `MAX` will have the largest prime number of the array stored in it. Print this value of `MAX`. Now for getting the positions where `MAX` happens, just iterate over the whole loop and check for the values that match `MAX` and print their positions:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(arr[i]==MAX)
    cout<<i+1<<" ";
}
```

I ran this code in `Dev C++ 5.11` and the compilation time was `0.72s`.